# What is the purpose of apps.py in Django 1.9?

Tags: django

I just went over the [alpha release notes for Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/) and saw that the `startapp` management command [now adds an apps.py file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#management-commands).

What's the purpose of this file? The [startapp documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-startapp) didn't provide more information.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

**Purpose of `apps.py` file:**

This file is created to help the user include any [application configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#application-configuration) for the app. Using this, you can configure some of the attributes of the application.

From [`Application Configuration`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#application-configuration) documentation:

> Application configuration objects store metadata for an application.
>   Some attributes can be configured in AppConfig subclasses. Others are
>   set by Django and read-only.

**Example from the [docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/applications/#for-application-authors)**

Lets say you’re creating a pluggable app called `"Rock ’n’ roll"`, then to provide a proper name for the admin we can do the following:

In `rock_n_roll` app, we create a `RockNRollConfig` AppConfig class.

```
#rock_n_roll/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class RockNRollConfig(AppConfig): # Our app config class
    name = 'rock_n_roll'
    verbose_name = "Rock ’n’ roll"
```

We can make your application load this `AppConfig` subclass by default by specifying the `default_app_config` in the `rock_n_roll/__init__.py` file.

```
# rock_n_roll/__init__.py    
default_app_config = 'rock_n_roll.apps.RockNRollConfig'
```

Doing this will cause `RockNRollConfig` to be used when `INSTALLED_APPS` just contains `'rock_n_roll'`. This allows us to make use of `AppConfig` features without requiring our users to update their `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: Sadly I didn't get your answer though

Comment: `without requiring our users to update their INSTALLED_APPS setting.` : What does this mean: Basically if i dont do `default_app_config = 'rock_n_roll.apps.RockNRollConfig'` then i have to mention in INSTALLED_APPS `default_app_config = 'rock_n_roll.apps.RockNRollConfig'`

Answer (score 16):

It is the recommended place to put your [application configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#application-configuration). This feature has been here since 1.7, but to promote its use and enable easier configuration, the `apps.py` file has been added to the default app template.

Answer (score 0):

`apps.py` is just an alternate way to update your application related configuration and now when you create new app using below command

```
python manage.py startapp myapp
```

you don't need to update the `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`, above command will by default add below code into the respective `myapp/apps.py` file

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class myappConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'myapp'
```