# Adding new django rest framework app to settings

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm going through this tutorial: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/ and there's one thing I don't understand a bit. They are doing `python manage.py startapp snippets` and adding `'snippets.apps.SnippetsConfig'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. Why this and not `'snippets'`? When I start a new app no `apps` package gets created and neither `WhateverConfig`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using below djagno1.9 just add `snippets`. In older django versions `startapp` management command will not create apps.py. you have to create new apps.py.

For > Django 1.9
[apps.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#management-commands) creates with `startapp` command

```
(env) simple: python manage.py startapp snippets
(env) simple: find snippets 
snippets
snippets/models.py
snippets/tests.py
snippets/views.py
snippets/admin.py
snippets/__init__.py
snippets/apps.py   # your apps.py
snippets/migrations
snippets/migrations/__init__.py

(env) simple: cat snippets/apps.py 
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.apps import AppConfig


class SnippetsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'snippets'
```

The Rest-Framework Documentation Updated to Django 1.9.
[Commit updated tutorial for django 1.9 on GitHub](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/commit/35036aee158c086a784b3a4a8a238f1f1ab6ddc3)

Read more about [apps.py in django 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795227/what-is-the-purpose-of-apps-py-in-django-1-9)