# Pubnub always times out in Django app

Tags: python, django, heroku, pubnub

I'm building a Django app to listen to a Pubnub feed and store the messages in a database. I create a pubnub listener in my app's `apps.py`'s `AppConfig`'s `ready()` method.

Upon launching my app on Heroku, I get the really unhelpful error

```
2017-04-26T02:17:50.038060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 30 seconds of SIGTERM
2017-04-26T02:17:50.038060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2017-04-26T02:17:50.134619+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

I suspect django wants to clean up the AppConfig process and is getting upset that there is a pubnub object hanging around in there. Is that the problem? How do I fix it?

I also see that (at least implicitly by example) [Heroku recommends using the twisted interface.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pubnub#using-the-python-sdk) Is it bad that I'm not?

Here's the relevant code:

I created a mypubnub.py based on [Pubnub's hello world example](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/pubnub-python-sdk):

```
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.callbacks import SubscribeCallback


class MySubscribeCallback(SubscribeCallback):
    def presence(self, pubnub, presence):
        pass

    def status(self, pubnub, status):
        pass

    def message(self, pubnub, message):
        pass  # I'll actually do the storage here later


def create_pubnub():
    pnconf = PNConfiguration()
    pnconf.subscribe_key = 'sub-c-blargyblargblarg'
    pnconf.publish_key = 'pub-c-blargyblargblarg'
    pubnub = PubNub(pnconf)

    pubnub.add_listener(MySubscribeCallback())
    pubnub.subscribe().channels('achannel').execute()

    return pubnub
```

I instantiate that pubnub stuff in `apps.py`from django.apps import AppConfig

```
from .mypubnub import create_pubnub

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'myapp'

    def ready(self):
        pn = create_pubnub()
```

Comment: I am not Django expert or even Python but what is the scope/life cycle of your apps.py? If it is only running for the duration of a web request then that will be an issue since subscribe is a long running (always on) process. Let me know if that may be the issue.

Comment: @CraigConover I think thats quite possibly the problem. I'm also new to Django and, unlike most things in python, the scope of apps.py or the AppConfig object is not explicit. Its generally not clear to me where a persistent storage location might be with Django. If someone else could weight in on this point, that would be really helpful.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795227/what-is-the-purpose-of-apps-py-in-django-1-9 but in general, if you are subscribing from your server, it's a red flag. Subscribing from your server is the exception rather than the norm. Best practice would be to use [PubNub BLOCKS](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks/introduction) to POST each message that is published from within the PubNub Network to your server rather than have your server listen on a channel or every channel.

Comment: @CraigConover Oh, looks like I was approaching this completely wrong- thanks for the pointer. I just got a "hello world" version working with the Blocks. If you care to write up the answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Subscribing from Server is the Exception

While it is something that some PubNub customers do successfully, subscribing from your server side is typically the exception rather than the rule. It does have its proper use case though.

In this case, best practice would be to use [PubNub BLOCKS](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks/introduction) to `POST` each message that is published from within the PubNub Network to your server rather than have your server listen on a channel or every channel to do the same.