# Missing apps.py,using python 2.7.12 with django 1.8

Tags: django, python-2.7

Iam using **django** **1.8** with **python version** **2.7.12** which is the right combination.But when I run command `python manage.py startapp app_name`,no **apps.py** got created but i can see under app_name

**init**,
**admin,
models,
tests,
views,migrations** got created.
Does django **1.8** not create any **apps.py** or what am i missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The configuration of apps.py came new in Django 1.7 still Django does not create apps.py from your project till Django 1.9 release. This [docs](http://django-collin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/applications.html#django.apps.apps) may help you to understand the apps.py and how you can create it. Also checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795227/what-is-the-purpose-of-apps-py-in-django-1-9) for more clarification.

One more link to checkout for new in [django1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/#management-commands) and alpha release [notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.9/)