# Getting error for created new app in python

Tags: python, django

i am new in python, I have created new app as `crud`, i am using `django`, app is created, but when i run the server it gives me below error, not getting what exactl error in that, In `mysite/settings.py` i have added in `INSTALLED_APPS` added `crud.apps.CrudConfig` still getting this error

```
C:\Users\Nikul\PycharmProjects\mysite>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 134, in create
    % (mod_path, cls_name, ', '.join(candidates))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'crud.apps' does not contain a class 'CrudConfig'. Choices are: 'PollsConfig'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 272, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\PycharmProjects\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    path('crud/', include('crud.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\PycharmProjects\mysite\crud\urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\PycharmProjects\mysite\crud\views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .models import Choice, Question
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\PycharmProjects\mysite\crud\models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Nikul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 111, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class crud.models.Question doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Can anyone please help me what we need to do to resolve that error ?

Comment: Does your `apps.py` in your app contain app related config details?
Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32795227/what-is-the-purpose-of-apps-py-in-django-1-9 for more info.

Comment: Wow it started working, thanks a lot